# Langdetect: No Features in Text

Tags: python, nlp

I have a dataframe with text in each row (about 40,000) and I need to identify the language for each and then filter for English. I am having issues though, when I come across some fields in there that have only numbers. I understand the reason for the error, but the issue is that as soon as it comes across one of these fields, then the whole thing fails.

Is there a way to handle these errors where it can just label it as "error" or something like it and then move past and continue to process the rest of the records?

here is the code i have now. It identifies which record has an error, but then every other record after will fail, and nothing gets processed

```
language = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
   try:
       language.append(detect(str(row['text'])))
   except:
       language = 'error'
       print('this row has error', row[0])
df.loc[:, 'language'] = language
```

Comment: I think you want `language.append('error')` not `language = 'error'` Otherwise you are overwriting the language list to the string 'error'.

Comment: that did it thanks!